# Вызывается два события одним кликом

Tags: javascript

Имеется div блок с картинкой, внутри этого блока еще один - так же с картинкой (лайк)

На оба блока в onclick прикрепил вызов разных функций, при клике на лайк - отправка данных, при клике на картинку - увеличение фото.

Требуется чтобы при клике на картинку лайка - происходила только отправка данных, по факту срабатывают оба события.

Подскажите пожалуйста как при клике на лайк - не срабатывало и второе событие. Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код в студию где добавляются и обрабатываются события

Comment: `<div><img><img like></div>` — или, можно повесить обработчик на сам img, и обойтись без `stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавь в код обработки  клика по сердечку `event.stopPropagation();` где event  - аргумент функции-обработчика событий